# ElasticSearch match query to field that contains number

Tags: elasticsearch

In my data, I have field `name` that contains values like this

- 1234_Customer xxx
- 2345_Customer yyy
- 5678_Customer zzz

When I'm trying to do match query with text, it works

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "customer",
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to find using number at front (it's a customer ID), nothing shown up

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "123",
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something else to do before querying? Or I need to use different query?
I think it has something to do with pattern, since between number and first word is _ (underscore)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a [`prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) instead:

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "name": "123"
        }
    }
}
```